# How to fix android program?

Tags: android

I have just started coding android with java on eclipse, and I have been doing tutorials on youtube. I recently copied the following code from one of the tutorials, but when I run it, it says "Unfortunately (my app) has stopped" an I don't understand why...

```
package com.example.trythisout;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.SparseBooleanArray;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Trying extends ListActivity {

    ArrayList list = new ArrayList();

    ArrayAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_trying);

        Button add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);

        Button del = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDelete);

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice,list);

        OnClickListener listener = new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                EditText edit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.items);

                if(edit.getText().toString().equals(""))
                {
                    list.add(edit.getText().toString());
                    edit.setText("");
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please enter data", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        };

        OnClickListener listener2 = new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                SparseBooleanArray checkedItemsPosition = getListView().getCheckedItemPositions();

                int count = getListView().getCount();

                for(int i = count; i>=0; i--)
                {
                    if(checkedItemsPosition.get(i))
                    {
                        adapter.remove(list.get(i));
                    }
                }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };

        add.setOnClickListener((android.view.View.OnClickListener) listener);
        del.setOnClickListener((android.view.View.OnClickListener) listener2);

        del.setOnClickListener((android.view.View.OnClickListener) listener2);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.trying, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Please, include your stack trace.

Comment: Also include your layout files.

Comment: I don't get how are we supposed to "fix" a software. If it was hardware, we could fix it but we can only "solve" a problem about software, with given details(logcat,files) which are not given.

Comment: From what you've given us, it could be many things. Maybe a view couldn't be found. Maybe it is of the wrong type... We really need more information. Did you debug your app? Can you tell us, where the error occurs? Can you show us your logcat output?